# Why all videos on Browser/system stop playing?

Tags: video, gpu-driver

kernel: 16.04. The OS works fine, plays all videos but after some time videos playback just stops. It then requires me to restart the system and then all videos start playing again. This used to happen with me on ubuntu 13.10. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu...  Are you using 13.10 or 16.04?  the kernel is displayed by  `uname --kernel-version`

Comment: See, I have upgraded to 16.04 because of this problem. Earlier, I was using 13.10. Although, problem still persists.

Comment: What kind of videos?  Locally stored or YouTube?

Comment: Both. But it happens occasionally.